# How to calculate unique IP's in Django (1 unique IP per day)?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

**

### I'would like to calculate on many unique IP's have visited a page from my website, with maximum visit per IP per day = 1.

**

I have a model with various fields. 
Two of them are :

```
- date: created_at.strftime("%d-%m-%y, %H:%M")
- ip: request_ip
```

A example of these two informations would be :

```
- 2019-07-15 17:43:09
- 127.0.0.1
```

I tried a combinaisons of various Django's methods like : values, distinct, filter, etc. But I can't get the result I want.
Because I cannot change the format of my fields, the distinct method won't work because the date changes every second. It would have been nice to have a date format like ("%d-%m-%y) = without the seconds, minutes and hours.

This is why the following example won't work. I have as a result, all the IPs in my database.

Example :

```
ip_number = reward_views.objects.values('request_ip', 'created_at').distinct().count()
```

So I tried to put the informations, IPs and dates, in lists in order to modify the date format and do better manipulations on it.

```
try:
        all_views = reward_views.objects.all().order_by('-updated_at')
    except:
        return HttpResponse(status=500)


    all_dates = []
    for view in all_views:
            all_dates.append({
                'reward_creation_date': view.created_at.strftime("%d-%m-%y"),
                'user_ip': view.request_ip,
            })
    print (all_dates)
```

But I can't find any right method to calculate the total of unique IP per day, and ultimately, the total of unique IP of all time (with a maximum visit per IP per day = 1).

Should I calculate this without any method ? Should I put all IPs in one list and all dates in another one (all of them ordered the same way), and then try to delete all the same occurrences ? But how can apply the 24H rule ?

Thanks for your suggestions !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it ! 
I actually discovered the possibility to put raw SQL in Django.
So I added this :

```
cursor.execute('''
    SELECT COUNT(
        DISTINCT tracker.request_ip, 
        DATE(tracker.updated_at)
    )
    FROM tracker;               
''')
unique_ips = cursor.fetchone()
```

Don't forget to import :

```
from django.db import connection
```

It worked just fine ! Here's the link to the documentation : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#passing-parameters-into-raw

Still, if someone knows how to do it without any raw SQL, let me know ! :)